# IF ELSE Loop problem in Google Sheets API

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

The code below pulls data from a small form, searches for a unique ID "uid" in a sheet "dbs" and copies new information into the correct line on the sheet.  If am trying to finish the task by making it paste a new line to the bottom of the sheet if the person does not yet exist on the "dbs" sheet.

I have tried "if else" and "if", both looking for and not looking for "!== uid" and "".

(the copy to lines are // out for debugging only)

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function submitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var static = ss.getSheetByName("Static Data"); //static data sheet
  var dbs = ss.getSheetByName("DBS Information"); //dbs sheet
  var menu = ss.getSheetByName("Menu");
  var uid = menu.getRange('E8').getValue();
  var values = dbs.getDataRange().getLastRow();


  // Logger.log(values)

  //find row number

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {

      if (values[i][j] == uid) {
        row = values[i][j];
        var x = 1;
        var z = x + i;
        Logger.log(z);
        // static.getRange("F2:M2").copyTo(dbs.getRange((z),1), {contentsOnly:true});
      } else {
        var R = dbs.getLastRow().getvalue;
        Logger.log(R);
        // static.getRange("F2:M2").copyTo(dbs.getRange((R),1), {contentsOnly:true});
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: `if .. else` is a control structure, like loops are, but it isn't a loop. Just saying.

Comment: If I were you, I'd check what the actual value of your uid variable is, and inside the loop, also check what   values[i][j]  looks like.  And then tell us, plus tell us what you are logging for z and R

Comment: Hello George, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please provide an example sheet that contains your data (obviously after removing any personal information) and what would you like to accomplish? That would help us better understand the task you are trying to accomplish. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When uid = a uid in the list, Z = the row number,
when uid does not = a uid in the list i want R to equal the first empty row
but it skips it completely and Logger shows nothing for anything

Comment: uid is working faultlessly as a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting a `found` variable if the `uid` is found, and then checking it after the loops to see whether to add a new row.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function submitData() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var static = ss.getSheetByName("Static Data"); //static data sheet
    var dbs = ss.getSheetByName("DBS Information"); //dbs sheet
    var menu = ss.getSheetByName("Menu");
    var uid = menu.getRange('E8').getValue();
    var values = dbs.getDataRange().getLastRow();


    // Logger.log(values)

    //find row number

    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var row = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {

            if (values[i][j] == uid) {
                row = values[i][j];
                var x = 1;
                var z = x + i;
                Logger.log(z);
                found = true;
                break;
                // static.getRange("F2:M2").copyTo(dbs.getRange((z),1), {contentsOnly:true});
            }
        }
    };

    if (!found) {
        var R = dbs.getLastRow().getvalue;
        Logger.log(R);
        // static.getRange("F2:M2").copyTo(dbs.getRange((R),1), {contentsOnly:true});
    }
};
```

Comment: Paul, thank you so much, this has been my first js project and I really appreciate the help!  problem solved!